# Why I'm not able to see the loaded sequence movie clip while compositing..? It shows only black and white checks

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image]

Why I'm not able to see the loaded sequence movie clip while compositing?  It shows only black and white

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the movie clip. You are on frame 120 there, is the clip shorter than that? This would be a reason why it is not showing anything. Oh, and please take proper screenshots instead of photographs of your monitor, as this makes it harder to see details due to distortions, reflections, Moiré patterns etc.

Comment: The original video is of 23 secs. I have converted the frames of the vedio to jpeg which in total have 50 frames.. I have added the movie clip node and added all the frames then connected it with alpha over but the background is not coming... I'm making an anamorphic 3d vedio .. also, if I'm opening a new project in blender doing without any changes and adding the clip the background is working well.. .. please help it's my final project of the year and I'm not able to do anything...

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.